# iPhone SDK: Reversing the playback of a wav file

Tags: iphone, audio, nsarray, wav

Is it possible to reverse the playback of a wav file by:

1 Putting its samples into an array.

2 Reversing the array using:

`NSArray* reversedArray = [[wavedataarray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];`

3 Writing/Playing the reversed data stored in the reversed array.

If it is, how do I put a wave file's samples into an array, and how would this array of raw reversed data be put back into a playable audio file?

Comment: In case it helps, here's a tutorial on how to reverse the samples (not the bytes!) of your audio data:
https://medium.com/swlh/reversing-a-wav-file-in-c-482fc3dfe3c4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that should work for PCM (uncompressed) data.  If it is in some other format it will need to be converted to a PCM format.

But using an NSArray will be problematic, each sample will have to be wrapped in an NSNumber and after the sort unwrapped.  Best to use a C array.

If the audio is PCM it should already be in a C array.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The audio is PCM and is a wav audio file in the documents directory, so how do I reference this C array?

Comment: NSMutableData *wav =[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; then: wav.bytes.  You can cast wav.bytes to a C array and exchange the  values in place.  Pay attention to the sample size and cast appropriately.